# What is the difference between OrderItemAddCmd vs. OrderItemUpdateCmd?

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-7, websphere-commerce, wcs

For IBM's WebSphere Commerce, what are some distinguishing differences between these two commands? They share OrderItemBaseCmd and do a lot of the same things.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Also, how is this Q related to Java?

Comment: An honest question for a newbie...can't many questions be "Have you done such and such and get the answer yourself?" But the documentation looks as if they are exactly the same for these two.

Comment: @jlordo and it is related to Java only because IBM WebSphere Commerce is built on Java. Is that OK?

Comment: You should have stated that same documentation in your question. Sorry I can't help you better, I clicked on the Q because it's tagged with Java, but I don't see anything to do with Java here.

Comment: @jlordo Organizers are free to retag and the answerer will probably need to know Java.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on OrderItemUpdate:

"This command can do all that OrderItemAdd command can do. In addition, it can also update products and items in the existing order list.".

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.commerce.developer.doc%2Frefs%2Frosorderitemupdate.htm

Answer (score 0):

OrderItemAdd command is invoked when you add an item to the shopping cart. Which involves making entry into orderItems table and updating the Orders table.

Later, suppose you want to update that item in the cart like increase the quantity of items. Since the item is already in the database respective to the order, It is desired to only update those rows with the new quantity and the related price details. Hence, we would call the OrderItemUpdate controller command.